# Checking database availability with Spring MVC to force a redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm implementing Spring MVC but would like to redirect if one of my database goes offline. Is there any easy way to check this? The application uses several databases (one for authentication etc.) so I need a graceful way of handling database issues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

For every `dataSource` run something like:

```
new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).queryForInt("SELECT 1").
```

Your `dataSource` might be configured to test connection before returning it, so in some cases it won't even reach query when database is down. To make the code simple, wrap this code in aspect around all your controllers.

More clean but a bit less flexible solution is to use some custom exception mapper that will catch database exceptions (Spring provides nice JDBC exceptions abstraction layer) and redirect appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect to the database, and if you can't, then redirect.