# Checking a DB connection made by a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, oracle10g

I am responsible for maintaining a bunch of legacy code which involves several deployed servlets; some through Tomcat 5.5 (yes I know - I did say legacy code!) and others through Glassfish 3.3.  All connect using the ojdbc14 driver, to Oracle 10 databases.  All use pooled connections.

However, occasionally, the connection to the DB is dropped, the DB restarts, etc., and the servlets fail until someone notices and they are re-deployed.  Not.  Cool.  I understand there is some way to monitor the DB connection the servlet makes, so that, in the event of a lost connection, the servlet 'knows' - how do I accomplish this?  And, can I make the servlet smart enough to recover itself by reinstigating the DB conection?   I've searched around for an answer, but I have not been successful.  Suggestions and pointers muchly appreciated.. I'm a bit of a newbie at this. Thanks!

Comment: What class/library provides the pool?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256474, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155214, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481644

Comment: I *think* it's DriverManager, guessing from the code (like I said, new at this) or do you mean the OJDBC14 driver?

Comment: Is it the case that the servlets should be using DataSource vs. DriverManager? I saw something on oracle that implied this. But if so I'm surprised it was coded this way in the first instance.